# Getting Error "java.io.IOException: Missing cursor chunk (offset 7000, count 400)"

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch class which I deployed to production instance, I am getting following error:

> Developer script exception from ClinetOrgName: 'MyBatchApexClassName' :
>   java.io.IOException: Missing cursor chunk (offset 7000, count 400),
>   key: V:SFDC::N/00************A4/L/01************X/0.cursor, failCount:
>   0, failServers: , missingCount: 3, errorMessages:

Anyone has faced this issue before? What could be the cause of this error.

Comment: looks like an internal SF code (java) exception that is accidentally bubbling up.  If I had to guess it would be related to batch serialization. Are you by chance using `database.stateful` or perhaps a customer `iterator`?

Comment: @NSjonas Yes I am using database.stateful but will that cause any issue ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error or was it a once-off?

Comment: Report this to salesforce.com. This is apparently something internal that shouldn't happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: @KeithC This is happening intermittently

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes I have raised the case to Salesforce